# Why do I often receieve `no such process` in response to a process I want to kill?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, kill, ps

```
me@me:~$ ps aux | grep -i firefox
me     15413  0.0  0.0  14428  1036 pts/1    S+   05:46   0:00 grep --color=auto -i firefox
me@me:~$ kill 15413
bash: kill: (15413) - No such process
```

Why might this happen, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you see what process it was?

```
me     15413  0.0  0.0  14428  1036 pts/1    S+   05:46   0:00 grep --color=auto -i firefox
                                                               ~~~~
```

It was the `grep` itself, it had already finished when you got the prompt back, so there was nothing to kill. Use `psgrep` for searching in the running processes, or at least use the "square brackets first character" trick

```
ps aux | grep -i '[f]irefox'
```

to exclude the grep from the match.

Comment: Ah, I did not notice that. It has my command attached to the end of it. 

`--color=auto` is aliased into my grep, which I didn't think of and sort of didn't read that as what it was.  

I'm getting used to sifting through a lot of excess information that I often unintentionally disregard some things to find what I'm looking for.  

I'm still getting the hang of where what I'm looking for is located sometimes. 

Typically processes that I need killed, I cannot find the means to kill them though and just do a reboot. It's not often though.

I will try some of those commands.